# SSIS 2008 R2 - Convert Oracle Character set data (with french accent)

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008, character-encoding, ssis

I'm trying to extract data out of an Oracle database that is configured with the following:
NLS_CHARACTERSET    EE8ISO8859P2
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16

I'm working with SSIS 2008 R2 Standard (had to install Oracle 11g Client).  Some accent are properly interpreted (e.g: é) but some are received as weird character and I can't find any way to convert them properly :(  The Oracle database is used by our ERP that serves many countries around the world which probably explains the character set choice (I'm not debating if it's a good one or not, I'm a SQL Server guy, not Oracle).

I've tried different approach to extract the data from Oracle, none of which succeeded.  I thought I could simply use something as:

```
SELECT CONVERT(FIELDNAME,'UTF8','EE8ISO8859P2') FROM xxx
```

Without success..  In my ERP I can see the following value:
"modèle" which is read "modcle" with the previous query through SSIS.

I kinda feel that there's no way I'm gonna get the proper data unless there's some magic formula that can be used.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set your NLS parameters using some `ALTER SESSION` commands.

Guess the parameter you need to change would be `NLS_LANG`

See this page for more information:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a76966/ch2.htm

Strangely, I helped one of my teammates today to sort in Swedish using this. Hope it helps you too.

Comment: Hmmm...  I think I might need more than that.  I've just connected using SQL Plus to to isolate my problem and avoid dealing with SSIS for now.  I've issued the command SELECT * FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS; an the result for NLS_LANGUAGE is already CANADIAN FRENCH.  However, characters are still incorrect when I issue my Select statement on my string table... :(

Comment: did you try Alter session. May be these NLS settings are set on your client SQL Developer and does not impact the data coming from the server!

Comment: Yes I did, no success :(